# AMD A12-9720P + Radeon RX 540 vs Intel I5 7200U + NVIDIA 940MX - Which is the best?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, gaming

I'm choosing between two laptops from Acer:

1. A515-41G-1480: (1) **CPU**: AMD A12-9720P 2.7Ghz (2) **RAM**: 8GB DDR4 (3) **GPU**: Radeon RX 540 2GB DDR5 (4) **HD**: 1TB;
2. A515-51G-50W8: (1) **CPU**: Intel Core i5-7200U 2.5 - 3.1Ghz (2) **RAM**: 8GB DDR4 (3) **GPU**: NVIDIA GeForce 940MX 2GB DDR5 (4) **HD**: 1TB;

The first one is 13,5% cheaper than the second one.

Now, in terms of RAM they are both the same. The obvious advantage of the second is the disk size which is double the first.

So it seems the choice boils down to the distinction: AMD A12 + Radeon 540 against Intel I5 7200U + GeForce 940MX.

I've seem that AMD A12 is quad-core while Intel I5 is dual core, so that it seems at first that AMD A12 is better, but I might be totally wrong, since I've seem some benchmarks and it appears the I5 wins all of them.

Which is actually the best one? I will use it for software development (mainly .NET, .NET Core and Javscript), scientific research (in this scenario probably I'll just run Wolfram Mathematica and LaTeX) and I would like to use it for gaming too, although I would be already happy running things in medium settings.

Comment: What's your total budget? I think there are probably better options than both of these.

Comment: Well, I'm from Brazil so that prices might be different from other countries. I'm trying to pay at most something around R$ 3000,00 (which today is the same as something around $ 815,00 in US currency). Interestingly I've found a third option: one Acer A515-51g-c1cw Intel Core I7-8550 with 12GB RAM and GeForce MX130 2GB DDR5. This one has a discount and is being sold by R$ 3450,00 ($ 937,00). Do you think there would be some better option available?

Comment: The Acer is definitly a better solution, especially since you're willing to make calculations. MX130 is quite poor for gaming, but it's always a matter of compromise.

Comment: @JulesR, well, all of the three are Acer. Do you mean the last one I've mentioned in comment? By the way, for gaming is MX130 better or 940MX?

Comment: Yes I meant the third one. The MX 130 seem to be slightly better than the 940MX